# Probability of a big number that is composed of two special numbers to be multiple of 19

Tags: probability, probability-theory, modular-arithmetic, big-numbers

A big number, which is 117179 digits in length, was constructed by concatenation of only two special numbers, which are 40 and 8 (both 40 and 8 must be used). There are around 62870 of any of those two special numbers can be used at most. I would like to know what is the probability of observing a number less than 117179 digits to be multiple of 19 with the above mentioned constraints? The probability should also consider the reverse concatenation too.

The use case is as follows: Assume that someone encoded a book with such coding to embed a signature in it to check its integrity. One letter corresponds to 40 and the other corresponds to 8. When you concatenate the appearance of those letters with their correspondence numbers then you observe the big resulting number is multiple of 19. Then the question is what is the probability of observing such number by chance alone?

I was asked to clarify in the comments.
So here is  an example:
like if there is letter x in the text we replace it with 40 and if there is y we replace it with 8 in the book and concatenate only these numbers over all the book (excluding anything else, so the order matters). then we have a number like 4084040408840..........840408404040

Comment: Please explain:  "...was constructed by concatenation of only two special numbers, which are 40 and 8".

Comment: like if there is letter x in the text we replace it with 40 and if there is y we replace it with 8 in the book and concatenate only these numbers over all the book (excluding anything else, so the order matters). then we have a number like 4084040408840..........840408404040

Comment: Jeez... this is SO not clear from your posting.  Please update your posting accordingly as I doubt anyone else understood this method.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about it.

Comment: If you can't use each of $40$ and $8$ more than $30875$ times, then you can't get a number with more than $3\times30875$ digits, which is a lot less than $117179$. Something's broken.

Comment: The probability will be very close to $\frac{1}{19}$, since swapping the position of an $8$ and a $40$ changes the remainder when dividing by 19.

Comment: @1Rock The problem doesn't look that simple. It may be a too low probability. Do you mind providing a proof?

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you very much for spotting this. It is my mistake. The correct number should be around 62870. So this is approximate number. I was trying to simplify the problem and this number got confused.

Comment: By "around 62870 of those two special numbers can be used", do you mean that at most 62870 of each number is used in the concatenation, or are you providing a rough "guideline" as to how many we can use (i.e. we can still consider a string of 117179 8s)?

Comment: I mean at most 62870 but both 40 and 8 must be used. Although, I want to see the boundaries, in reality 40 is mostly used in the text.

Comment: OK, so, your big number has 117179 digits, but you're asking a question about a number with fewer than 117179 digits. So what does the big number with 117179 digits have to do with anything?

Comment: The big number is derived from a text and it is 117179 digits and multiple of 19. 62870 is the total number of those two letters with 40 and 8. I want to know, if we randomly select a text and observe such coding, what is the probability of observing it by chance alone. Therefore the, the current size of the text is selected as the upper limit.

Comment: If you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to give an exact answer, but the following argument suggests the answer is close to $\frac{1}{19}$. There are 8 possibilities for a string of 3 digits: 088,084,040,888,884,840,408,404. I haven't worked out exactly what proportion of the time the patterns 408 and 840 come up, but I expect they each come up at least $\frac{1}{20}$ of the time (i.e. $\frac{1}{10}$ of the time in total). That means there are at least roughly 4000 instances of either 408 or 840 in a 120,000-digit number, treating the number as a sequence of non-overlapping three-digit strings.

Now, $840-408\equiv 14\pmod{19}$, and $1000\equiv 12 \pmod{19}$. 19 is prime, so repeatedly multiplying by 12 hits all 18 possible nonzero remainders mod 19, before returning to the starting point. In roughly 1/18 of the instances of 408/840 (i.e. roughly 200 instances), changing from 408 to 840 would increase the remainder by 1, or changing from 840 to 408 would decrease the remainder by 1. Now, we can treat the number of instances of 408/840 in place values where increasing from 408 to 840 would increase the remainder by 1 as a $Binomial(200,0.5)$ random variable. Similarly, the places where going from 840 to 408 would increase the remainder by 1, or going from 408 to 840 would decrease the remainder by 1, give us another $Binomial(200,0.5)$ random variable, whose sum is a $Binomial(400,0.5)$ random variable. You can check that of the possible outcomes of a $Binomial(400,0.5)$ random variable, the probability of each remainder when you divide by 19 is roughly constant, with variation in only the 4th decimal place. Thus, considering only those patterns is enough to show the probability is roughly $\frac{1}{19}$, to 3 decimal places.

Comment: I couldn't follow the explanation of the proof. But if it is around 1/19 then this means around 5% of All the possible numbers until up to 117179 digits length should be multiple of 19. With the constrains of 40 and 8 components, this doesn't seem to be possible. The probability of 1/19 is the probability of a random number being multiple of 19. There should be a difference. there is a large space of numbers without 40 and 8 in the full number space.

Comment: The key point is that "only using 40s and 8s" is independent of "being divisible by 19" for large numbers. There are lots of multiples of 19 which include numbers other than 40 and 8, but there are also lots of non-multiples of 19 which include numbers other than 40 and 8. 19 is coprime with 40, 8 and 10, so combinations of those numbers don't behave any differently to typical numbers in terms of their remainder mod 19.

Comment: It would be different if you were considering remainders mod 5 or mod 2, since that's not coprime with 10, or if you were considering remainders mod 27 and only using 3s and 9s, since those aren't coprime with 27. But it would be the same if you were only using 2s, 3s and 9s and considering remainders mod 27, since there would be a "random" number of 2s which would cause the remainders to be random.

Comment: Thanks, it looks you are right.